# Combining @NonBlocking with HIbernate ORM during application startup

Tags: quarkus

In my application I need to initialize content from a database at startup.

The following article: https://quarkus.io/blog/resteasy-reactive-smart-dispatch/ mentions the following.

"As Hibernate ORM classic (we also have Hibernate reactive) is blocking, you can’t use it with RESTEasy reactive without using the @Blocking annotation. This annotation changes the dispatching strategy to use a worker thread (instead of the I/O thread)."

It goes on that stuff has been simplified by looking at the signature of the method called. If you  signature implies synchronous behavior, the "worker thread" is chosen. If not, the (faster) reactive mechanism is preferred (i/o thread).

It also mentions Hibernate reactive as opposed to Hibernate classic. I've not explored into that realm yet.

---

But, starting from here I want to try to do the following:

```java
@Startup 
@ApplicationScoped
public class I18NBean{

   public static Map<String, String> I18N = init();


   private static Map<String,String> init(){

        // initialize map from DB
   }

   public String translate(String in){
       return I18N.get(in);
   }
}
```

```java
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

  @Inject
  I18NBean translations;

   @POST
   @NonBlocking
   public String hello( String in ) {
       return translations.translate( in );
   }
}
```

making use of the I/O thread for the resource and doing the hibernate (classic) interaction at startup.

The simple question: would that work? I am going to try this myself coming days, but perhaps there are some fundamental things that I overlook or perhaps there's a better strategy / designs such as using a lifecycle method.

```java
    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {               
        LOGGER.info("The application is starting...");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work. The idea is that you should be using normal Hibernate on worker threads, while Hibernate Reactive should be used on Vert.x Event Loop threads

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I'll try it out this week and get back on this.

Comment: I got an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple matching properties for name "security.jaxrs.deny-unannotated-endpoints" property was matched by both public boolean io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.runtime.JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs and public boolean io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs. This is likely because you have an incompatible combination of extensions that both define the same properties (e.g. including both reactive and blocking database extensions)

Comment: after inclusion of dependency: <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>

Comment: You can't have both `quarkus-resteasy` and `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` together

Comment: I use a comon library. Exclusion of the `quarkus-resteasy` from that comon library and adding `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` gives a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/quarkus/resteasy/runtime/QuarkusRestPathTemplate`

Comment: and it seems that `quarkus-resteasy-jackson` is also dependent on `quarkus-resteasy`

Comment: Ah.. I see there's a `quarkus-reasteasy-jackson-reactive` as well. But that makes it hard to reuse in a common library (I need `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`)

Comment: A common library should likely only have to depend on the JAX-RS API

Comment: I know.. But I've got to deal with what I got. We use a lot standard interceptors to provide default functionality. They are tested inside Quarkus and hence all the dep's ended up on the transitive path. I marked them as optional now and cleaned the dependencies. Lets see where that brings me. But: is my assertion right that I need to use the "reactive" versions of the dependencies ('quarkus-resteasy-reactive') to get this to work? Or do the "non reactive" versions suffice..

Comment: Get what to work exactly? I got lost in what exactly you are asking

Comment: Well, if I read:  https://quarkus.io/blog/resteasy-reactive-smart-dispatch/ I'm left with the impression that using `@NonBlocking` is sufficient. But you'll need to change the maven dependencies as well. So for instance `<artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>` instead of `<artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>`

Comment: Everything you read in  quarkus.io/blog/resteasy-reactive-smart-dispatch is about RESTEasy Reactive (i.e. `quarkus-resteasy-reactive`)